# Postfix+Dovecot: emoji in subject from command line break the delivery ("SMTPUTF8 is required, but was not offered"), works from Gmail

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, dovecot, utf-8

**Tl;dr**: if I send an email to my Postfix+Dovecot server with the subject containing UTF-8 characters

- **email from Gmail** => Postfix+Dovecot deliver the email correctly
- **email from mail (command line)** => Postfix+Dovecot fail with the error `SMTPUTF8 is required, but was not offered by host example.com[private/dovecot-lmtp]`

`smtputf8_enable = no` makes no difference.

---

[I understood](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/402684/104537) that Dovecot doesn't support smtputf8 yet, but I'm not really sure about the practical implication of it.

I setup my Ubuntu 22.04 system with Postfix, dovecot-lmtp and Dovecot. Everything works as expected and I'm already using it in production to receive emails from the Internet, but I'm testing the issue with smtputf8 specifically.

**Test 1: Email from Gmail to Postfix**

As the first test case, I configured Postfix WITHOUT `smtputf8_enable = no`. So this means "no change from default" => the smtputf8 support is enabled.

From here, I sent an email from an external Gmail account to my Postfix+Dovecot managed address with this subject:

`Hello, this is a test with UTF-8 ❣❤✡⚗`

Result: SUCCESS! Email received correctly all the way.

**Test 2: Email from command line to Postfix**

Same configuration as before. This time I connected to an external server (running Ubuntu 22.04 with Postfix) via SSH and sent an email via command line like this:

`echo "Test from $(hostname)" | mail -s "Hello, this is a test with UTF-8 ❣❤✡⚗" -a FROM:foo@foo.com me@example.com`

The subject is exactly (copy/paste) the one used from Gmail.

Result: FAILURE! Postfix receives the email, but then it cannot deliver it to Dovecot:

`postfix/lmtp[31775]: D2E1C475E0: to=<me@example.com>, relay=mailserver.example.com[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=2.2, delays=2.2/0/0.09/0, dsn=5.6.7, status=bounced (SMTPUTF8 is required, but was not offered by host mailserver.example.com[private/dovecot-lmtp])`

**Test 3: Email from command line to Gmail, forward to Postfix**

Ok, let's send the email from the command line to my external Gmail account, then forward it to my Postfix+Dovecot managed address.

Result: SUCCESS! It looks like Gmail has no problem receiving my email from the command line, then it works some kind of magic and the forward makes it compatible with my Postfix+Dovecot setup.

**Test 4: Email from Gmail to Postfix with smtputf8_enable = no**

Let's change the postfix config to:

`smtputf8_enable = no`

This is what most tutorial recommend.

From here, I sent an email from an external Gmail account to my Postfix+Dovecot managed address with this subject:

`Hello, this is a test with UTF-8 ❣❤✡⚗`

Result: SUCCESS! I expected it to fail, but it made absolutely NO DIFFERENCE from test 1!

**Test 5: Email from command line to Postfix with smtputf8_enable = no**

This fails, exactly like Test 2.

Comment: Gmail sends the subject as MIME encoded. `mail` sends it as is.

Comment: Interesting, thanks @AlexD ! Is it possible to MIME-encode from mail as well?

Comment: You can encode a string to pass as a subject using some external tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most message content, an 8bit SMTP transport is not necessary, because the characters can be expressed in a 7bit encoding. **Use a client capable of applying valid [encoding](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2047) to the headers** you want to use non-ASCII characters in. Drafting your message in most full-features MUAs will do, your Webmail interface is just one example. Open the source of the message received via Gmail to see how sch encoding looks in practice.

As far as I can tell, progress has stalled on both other possible solutions:

1. There has for some time been interest in having Postfix apply the necessary transformations to relay an 8bit message to a 7bit transport, but it is somewhat tricky, and cannot deal with recipient address localparts anyway (as those do not allow the Q/P encoding workaround).
2. Dovecot could be patched to offer an 8-bit transport, but there are quite a few edge cases and I would not expect that to be entirely production-ready for a long time.

Until then, your probably do *not* want to offer smtputf8 in Postfix, and are limited by the capabilities of the mail clients you use.